# How do hide iPod icon with SBSettings?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

On my Jailbroken iPad, I have SBSettings installed. I chose to hide all my application icons, but iPod will not go away, no matter what the switch setting is. I was thinking about just going into the file system and manually deleting the icon, but I don't know where it's stored.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used [Saurik's guide on theming](http://www.saurik.com/id/9) and made my own iPod icon, a transparent 57 x 57 PNG. Kinda rudimentary, but it works for now. I then used [iBlank](http://iphonehelp.in/2009/01/08/iblank-create-blank-icons-on-iphones-springboard-via-cydia-free/) to hide the shadow. Works for now lol....even though, the iPod is still selectable, kinda gotta be lucky to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running OS 3.1.x or 4.0.x? I've had some inconsistencies with hiding certain icons on my jailbroken 4.0.1 phone. It may be that SBSettings isn't fully compatible with OS 4.x yet.

edit: Fail on my behalf. Somehow I missed "iPad" in both your question AND tag. /facepalm

Comment: I'm on iPad (3.2.1). Now that you mention it, I have heard that there are some compatibility issues with certain jailbroken apps in 3.2....I think I'll just delete the iPod application and see what happens lol